# How to disable mouse wheel scroll of ScrollPane in As3?

Tags: actionscript-3, scrollpane

I was playing around with ScrollPane options in order to disable the wheel scroll functionality of the vertical bar. Tried `myScrollPane.mouseEnabled = false;`, `myScrollPane.mouseWheelEnabled = false;` with no luck. Also, `myScrollPane.verticalLineScrollSize = 0;` also did not seem to result in desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okkkk this should be what you're looking for!

```
myScrollPane.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, disableScroll, true);
function disableScroll(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not looking to disable the scroll bar completely. I only seek to disable the scroll event that happens when scrolling up or down with mouse wheel.

Comment: Oh, I must've read your question wrong then. Why do you need to disable the event?

Comment: oh, wait..you just don't want the wheel to work..gotcha..hold on haha

Comment: ok, i've edited my initial response. That should be what you're looking for